# Powershell magnling ascii text

Tags: powershell, ascii

I'm getting extra characters and lines when trying to modify hosts files. For example, this select string does not take anything out, but the two files are different:

```
get-content -Encoding ascii C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts |
  select-string -Encoding ascii -notmatch "thereisnolinelikethis" |
  out-file -Encoding ascii c:\temp\testfile

PS C:\temp> (get-filehash C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts).hash
C54C246D2941F02083B85CE2774D271BD574F905BABE030CC1BB41A479A9420E

PS C:\temp> (Get-FileHash C:\temp\testfile).hash
AC6A1134C0892AD3C5530E58759A09C73D8E0E818EC867C9203B9B54E4B83566
```

Comment: This might be because `Get-Content` returns an array, and the process of breaking the file into an array and writing it back out as a string may introduce an extra line break or two.

Comment: It is the Select-String that is adding the extra lines... really curious as to why

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that your commands do inexplicably result in extra line breaks in the output file, in the start and in the end. Powershell also converts the tabs in the original file into four spaces instead.

While I cannot explain why, these commands do the same thing without these issues:

Try this code instead:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Encoding Ascii | 
  Where-Object { -not $_.Contains("thereisnolinelikethis")  } |
  Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\testfile" -Encoding Ascii
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more of an issue with PowerShell's F&O (formatting & output) engine.  Keep in mind that `Select-String` outputs a rich object called MatchInfo.  When that object reaches the end of the output it needs to be rendered to a string. I think it is that rendering/formatting that injects the extra line.  One of the properties on MatchInfo is the line that was matched (or notmatched).  If you pass just the Line property down the pipe, it seems to work better (hashes match):

```
Get-Content C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts |
    Select-String -notmatch "thereisnolinelikethis" |
    Foreach {$_.Line} |
    Out-File -Encoding ascii c:\temp\testfile
```

BTW you only need to specify ASCII encoding when outputting back to the file.  Everywhere else in PowerShell, just let the string flow as Unicode.

All that said, I would use `Where-Object` instead of `Select-String` for this scenario.  Where-Object is a filtering command which is what you want. Select-String takes input of one form (string) and converts it to a different object (MatchInfo).

Answer (score 0):

`Out-File` adds a trailing NewLine (`` "`r`n" ``) to the `testfile` file.

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` does not contain a trailing newline out of the box, which is why you get a different FileHash

---

If you open the files with a `StreamReader`, you'll see that the underlying stream differs in length (due to the trailing newline in the new file):

```
PS C:\> $Hosts = [System.IO.StreamReader]"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
PS C:\> $Tests = [System.IO.StreamReader]"C:\temp\testfile"
PS C:\> $Hosts.BaseStream.Length
822
PS C:\> $Tests.BaseStream.Length
824
PS C:\> $Tests.BaseStream.Position = 822; $Tests.Read(); $Tests.Read()
13
10
```

ASCII characters 13 (`0x0D`) and 10 (`0x0A`) correspond to `[System.Environment]::NewLine` or [CR+LF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)

Comment: Ok but why? and where does the leading new line come from?

Comment: @Cole9350 it doesn't come from anywhere, `Out-File` just adds it by default, "to be nice" if you will

Comment: No your missing the part how it is adding a new line at the top of the file.. Its a trailing newline and a leading newline, and it happens in select-string not out-file

Comment: @Cole9350 `Out-File` is not adding it at the top of the file. `Select-String` is doing that, which is why I suggest not using it in my answer.